# Storing array as a single record in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Can I store an array such as `[1,2,3,4]` or some JSON like `{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo, "phone":"5551234567"}` as one record in mysql? If yes, is it really a good approach or for better result, Is it better to separate those and store in individual column and define the relationship? What is the good method in php to handle this?

EDIT: I want to make clear about what I wanted to do. I am using jquery UI and want to store the position of draggable and droppable in array format. The draggable and droppable will be identified with their ID along with their position so that they can be queried back and be created in the next html page whenever user wants to. I am not sure whether I have to explode those arrays, say like, in separate field like FROM_TOP, FROM_LEFT or just one array storage is sufficient. I was also little concerned about the efficiency.

Comment: Don't know why I got flagging for my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can; it is a bad idea.** This violates something called *normalization*. You should have things separated out into individual columns and tables (as needed). It would require a lot of work to maintain the data in the JSON. Just think, you would have to update the whole record in PHP then update the record.

Say I just want to update the phone number...

Bad:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `Data` = '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo, "phone":"5551234567foo"}'
```

Good:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `Phone` = '5551234567foo'
```

Another reason this would be bad... querying would be slow with LIKE and very hard to be deterministic. Say you have a fax number field... which one would it be with the bad example?

Bad:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Data` LIKE '%5551234567%'
```

Good:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Phone` = '5551234567'
```

PHP really doesn't deal with the schema or handling the data directly, so there is no method to directly handle that. It's all done in the SQL.

Comment: I really don't think, in my case for this purpose, I will have any reason to update the data within the fields. I just want to store them as they are and retrieve them back. Based on your idea, I guess it will not be so bad if I refrain from the situation where I want to do any manipulation inside the data field.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to encode and decode json you can store it as TEXT in your Mysql Database...

It goes against the norms as usually you have normalize then into different tables.... but if this is your only way then use TEXT

Comment: what do you mean by relations... you have any other tables ? IF you need a relationship you must have them on different columns....

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you are going to do with the data...

You can serialize() your data and store it in one database field or you can separate it and make is accessible from MySQL connections (use it to perform searches etc). If it is always standard (i.e. always has the same fields) save it in it's own fields, if it's just a random array the first method is fine

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not wrong . Sometimes, you may have to keep data in such format . i have seen this in many applications . Ex : keeping a regular expression or pattern like this . But this is a bad idea , considering database design guidelines . If you want to do a update query on this field, or change a portion of text in the field etc, at that time it would be a difficult task . If possible, keep the data in separate table with many rows .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
 serialize($item);
```

to store array of data into one field

then

```
  unserialize($row['field_name']);
```

tor retrieve it

I found this to be an easy way to store a copy of a data set for revision

i would not use this as a primary method of storing data in a table though one i put it the column it there i don't try to manipulate it again. I just use it for storage

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just remember that you should not try to search within those fields. Horrible performance would be expected. Is it perfect design following normalization? No, but it still works.

Doctrine2 has a field type to do this automatically and abstract the serialization logic from you. However, it means getting to use the whole ORM.

If you go this route, I would advise you handle database migrations using scripts. This way, if your requirements ever change and you need to search one of the values contained, you can always write a simple migration and update your data. Modifying a schema should not be a burden.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, MySql supports JSON natively see- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html.

As to the "horrible" performance, its not really an issue now, we use this in our production servers storing and querying millions of rows an hour. MySql has also branched out into NoSql territory so the claim that normalization is always right is bs.

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(JSON_COLUMN_NAME) VALUES (
    '{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo, "phone":"5551234567"}'
);
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding an example how it actually *does* work (instead of providing a link only).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) when putting the array in the database and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) when extracting from the database.